# Get Geolocation by IP (Spigot 1.8 & 1.13.2)

Tags: java, geolocation, minecraft, bukkit

i Want to find out the geolocation by only providing the ip adress.
My Aim is to save city, country, postal code and other informations.

```
CraftPlayer cp = (CraftPlayer)p;
String adress = cp.getAddress();
```

Any short possibilities, to find out by only using ip?

Comment: Use an API like this one : https://www.baeldung.com/geolocation-by-ip-with-maxmind

Comment: Do you want to host your own local database for query? If yes, you can download and use the free database from https://lite.ip2location.com/database/ip-country-region-city-latitude-longitude-zipcode

Comment: Yes, hosting own database would be great. The ip2loc database looks good. Is there any simple possibility, to return information from file by only providing ipv4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using http://ip-api.com/docs/api:newline_separated

You can then chose what information you need and create your HTTP-link like:

http://ip-api.com/line/8.8.8.8?fields=49471

The result in this example would be:

```
success
United States
US
VA
Virginia
Ashburn
20149
America/New_York
```

So you can create a method in Java to read HTTP and split it at `\n` to get the lines:

```java
private void whatever(String ip) {
    String ipinfo = getHttp("http://ip-api.com/line/" + ip + "?fields=49471");
    if (ipinfo == null || !ipinfo.startsWith("success")) {
        // TODO: failed
        return;
    }
    String[] lines = ipinfo.split("\n");
    // TODO: now you can get the info
    String country = lines[1];
    /*
    ...
     */
}

private static String getHttp(String url) {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(url).openStream()));
        String line;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        br.close();
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

just make sure not to create to many querys in a short amount of time since ip-api.com will ban you for it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of websites that provide free databases for IP geolocation.

Examples include:

- [MaxMind](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/)
- [IP2Location](https://lite.ip2location.com/)

At the plugin startup you could download one of these databases and then query it locally during runtime.

If you choose do download the .bin format you will have to initialize a local database and then import the data. Otherwise you could just use the csv file with a Java library like [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net).

From the documentation of opencsv:

> For reading, create a bean to harbor the information you want to read,
>   annotate the bean fields with the opencsv annotations, then do this:
>
> ```java
> List<MyBean> beans = new CsvToBeanBuilder(FileReader("yourfile.csv"))
>     .withType(Visitors.class).build().parse();
> ```

Link to documentation: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net